# Showing a collage of movie posters

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects

I need to show a group of a dozen or so movie posters in an interesting way in one graphic using Photoshop CS5. I've rotated them and added drop shadows/borders to all. How do I add a cloud background? These are high-res images and the canvas is about 6000 px wide, so a raster image probably won't work.

Also, can you give a "3D" effect to the images so they have perspective? Thanks.

Comment: you should read this : http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/faq

Comment: Sorry, this is a brainstorming question. I think if you post what you have and ask "How can I improve X feature of this?" (how can I make it more edgy, more like Mad Men, more like a horror film) it can be answered, but not as written.

Comment: Thanks, Lauren Ipsum. How's the question now?

Comment: I would suggest you to google this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve a 3D-like effect on an individual poster by skewing it - hold Ctrl and drag one of the corners. I don't know of a way to apply the same perspective to all posters, but perhaps you could do it manually by creating perspective lines yourself and skewing each poster to match them.

As for the cloud texture, I'd have a look at using a brush of some sort and playing about with what looks good. A good place to go for brushes is DeviantArt, but here's a pack I found after a little Googling. http://qbrushes.net/nature/cloud-brushes-high-resolution/